# Placeholder on canvas of ChartJs and Angular

Tags: angularjs, html, chart.js

I am using ChartJS with Angular (with this angular directive: http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js).
I wanted to know if it is possible to put a placeholder from see when the chart data are all 0.
For example I have a chart with

$scope.data = [0,0,0];
$scope.labels = ["first", "second", "third"];

Is possible to print only the placeholder? or put one by default?

Comment: could you share use what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can trun on the legend and override the legend template to show the values in the legend

```
$scope.options = {
    legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%>: <%=segments[i].value%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
};
```

If you want to show the value only if they are 0, just add an if condition

```
$scope.options = {
    legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%if(segments[i].value === 0){%>: <%=segments[i].value%><%}}%></li><%}%></ul>"
};
```

Working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/s2t3quwp/

If all your data points are 0, you will see not chart, but you can still see the legend.